# How to customize WordPress Thickbox?

Tags: thickbox

I've been able to do a certain amount of styling via CSS, but I'd like to add divs and more to the navigation elements - in other ords, I need to be able to somehow edit the actual js file, but obviously don't want to do so since it would just be overwritten on future updates.  Surely there are functions/hooks that would make this possible?  Or, would it work similar to how other theme files operate in that simply creating an identical file structure (includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js) within my theme it would automatically overwrite it?

Help! The out-of-the-box layout is way too generic for my tastes.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Since the link is unavaiable anymore (linked a webarchive in comments but it's still pretty old and buggy) I suggest to use [this](https://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/en/tutorials/customize-checkbox-and-radio-button-with-css).

It's more efficient and reliable and does not require any file add-in or advanced knowledge being more detailed than the old one.

**Original**

I've bumped into this one before.

Here, follow this tutorial:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

But be carefull, if you want to use it on Woocommerce checkout/cart pages, it will bug the hole page (haven't managed to solve that one), but besides that works like a charm, have fun!

Comment: Many thanks. I did ultimately figure it out (and I wasn't using WooCommerce so I will bear that in mind if I need to do the same thing in there. Thanks for the heads-up).

Comment: @Eduard link is broken

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam https://web.archive.org/web/20161007180651/http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/